# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions - error while working with ASP.NET MVC 2 and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

In **_Layout.cshtml** file I have following entry:

```
@Html.Action("LoadPagesStructure", "Page")
```

Inside **PageController** class, **LoadPagesStructure** methos looks following:

```
[ChildActionOnly] /* this attribute indicates that an action should not 
                     be invoked as a result of a user request (by url) */
public ActionResult LoadPagesStructure()
{         
    ViewModel.Pages = new List<string>() {"page1", "page2", "page3"};
    return View();
}
```

Finally, my **LoadPagesStructure.cshtml view** looks like below:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>

<ul>
    @foreach (var page in View.Pages) {
    <li>        
        @Html.ActionLink(page, "Index", "Home")
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, an exception is thrown after execution:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

What is the way of creating links to my pages dynamically ?

**PS:** I know that I can do this like that: `<a href="@page">@page</a>`. Nevertheless I think this is not the right way, because control of the routing is impossible here.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I think you might need to return a `PartialView` for your `LoadPagesStructure()` action.

Try this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoadPagesStructure()
{         
    ViewModel.Pages = new List<string>() {"page1", "page2", "page3"};
    return PartialView();
}
```