# PartialViewResult action gives error when ran from jquery function but not from @Render.Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that when I was working on during development was called by an @Html.Render action, rendered the partial view and worked just fine.

That partial view was rendering a table which inside had another @Html.RenderAction for each TR.
Like this:

```
<div id="fooDiv">
    @{Html.RenderAction("ProjectData", "Functional", new { categoryId = Model.SelectedCategoryId});}
</div>
```

Which renders several other Partials one of which is:

```
<div id="FuncTableWrapper">
    @{Html.RenderAction("FuncTable", Model.Id);}
</div>
```

Which renders:

```
<table id="funcTable">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <th class="thFuncLangName">@item.Name</th>
        }
    </tr>    
    @foreach (var funcFeature in Model.FuncFeatures)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="tdfuncFeatureName" colspan="@(Model.Categories.Count() + 1)">@funcFeature.Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trAddFuncContent hideThis">
            <td colspan="@(Model.Languages.Count() + 1)">
                @{Html.RenderAction("AddFuncContent", new { funcFeatureId = funcFeature.Id });}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine. However, the render should not be done on page load but only when I click on a tab, I decided to call that action from jquery and populate the div I needed at that point.

```
$("#FuncData").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ProjectData", "Functional")',
        data: { "CategoryId": @(Model.SelectedCategoryId) },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result) {
            populateDiv($("#fooDiv"), data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I do that I know get an error on the RenderAction calling the "AddFuncContent" action saying that "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

What difference is there between the page calling Html.RenderAction and javascript calling my action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the POST method may be the issue - on the initial page load you are probably in a get request, and POST is often set up to save something then redirect.

Another difference is that only the ajax version actually uses a Url. RenderAction can look for the named action method directly, so doesn't need to parse a Url. That means that it doesn't matter if there is not a valid route for the action, or the route could also point to a different action.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't that crash right at the call? The ajax post is calling the action correctly. It's actually when the view is rendered and has to call another RenderAction that it crashes.

Comment: Not if it is that second RenderAction that has different behaviour on post. Since the ajax call is for display rather than save, I'd suggest changing the method to "GET".

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't try cause I thought I couldn't pass a parameter when using a GET Oo It works!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you're returning PartialView() from your action. [See this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573554/asp-mvc-2-razor-child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions/3577104#3577104).

Comment: Hey John, my action does return a PartialView. I've also update the post as I forgot to mention I had an extra RenderAction. But I don't think that would affect this problem.

Comment: Are your other actions returning PartialView as well?

Comment: Yes, everything is returning a PartialView. Hence, why I'm stuck on this :D

Comment: Have you tried isolating this error in a sandbox application? No data, just the same basic structure of render action calls & the same jQuery  ajax call.

Comment: Nop, good idea, I'll try that first thing tomorrow when I get back to work ^^

I was thinking however, that there has to be something different between the Html.RenderAction and the $.ajax post that causes this to happen. I just can't put my finder on what it is.